# IPTables Block Many IPs Using Domain

Tags: iptables

```
DROP       all  --  114-43-XXX-XXX.dynamic.hinet.net  anywhere
DROP       all  --  118-161-XXX-XXX.dynamic.hinet.net  anywhere
```

These are just two of the several restrictions I have in IPTables right now because this person is constantly connecting to postfix. Luckily, the server does not allow him to send messages because relay access is denied. I would still like to block this person from accessing my server. Is there a way to block the whole group of IP's using dynamic.hinet.net instead of specifying IP Addresses everytime?

Comment: Please use the [contact](http://serverfault.com/contact) page to request that this profile be merged with your existing profile. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It's not a single person or a single PC you're seeing. It's just infected clients with botnets, which spammers use to find open relays so that they can send their junk. Keep the server running for a few months without deleting logs, and you'll find *millions* of them.

I suggest that you make 100% sure that your server does not allow relaying, and that you install simple extensions to your mail server to block of 99% of the attempts *without* filling your iptables ruleset.

The ones that come to mind:

- Strict SPF checking
- RBL's
- DKIM (not widely adopted yet)

All these provide very little overhead - everything is based on DNS which is an excellent transport for these kind of services. Make sure you use a DNS server that has a *large* cache available (like Googles).

Comment: Absolutely no need to use IpTables for a relay check - postfix can do that as easy and as well. Well said.

Comment: I would mark this as answer but I don't see the button. Presumably because not enough time has elapsed?

Comment: @JustinE Are you "jxrts"? If so then you're logged in with the wrong account..

Comment: Just logged in after asking the question because it didn't do it automatically...that's weird...the question was asked as a guest, and when I "completed the registration" it said the account already existed, so I logged in. I figured it would transfer the question to my account, but I guess not...just flagged for a moderator to look at it.